# Cookie doesn't expire when closing browser

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie with:

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $val, 0);
```

Or

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $val);
```

But when I close and re-open the browser (firefox, chrome) the cookie is still alive with the same value. How can I force it to delete when visit is over?

Thank you

Comment: That should work, how do you check the cookie existence?

Comment: if you're opening the page again and again to check for cookie, then it'll always be there.

Comment: Make sure you are closing the browser, not the tab!

Comment: Yes I close the browser and I'm triple checking it through Web developer plugin for firefox, chrome web developer tools and my own code. The solution was setting it to the past, thanks to all

Comment: Actually, setting it to past wasn't a solution as it doesn't keep the cookie between pages

Comment: I've noticed, at least on a Mac, that just because you x'd out of chrome, it is still running.  You have to go the Chrome menu and choose "Quit Google Chrome", and then it removes all the Session Cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete a cookie just set the expiry date to the past like so:

```
// Set the cookie in the past to ensure it is removed
setcookie($cookie_name, $val, time()-3600);
```

However, I do not think this is the issue in your case, as your code seems to be correct.

**How are you testing for the cookie? You are probably setting it again before testing for it!**

You will also want to make sure you are closing the browser not the tab. Closing a tab, does not end a session!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the value as null

```
setcookie($cookie_name, null);
```

Comment: This does delete the cookie in the past, it just makes the value null!

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $val, time()-3600);
```

Comment: Ooos, I marked this as answer but actually this deletes the cookie between page transitions, within the same session, so it's not what I need

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
setcookie ("TestCookie", "", time() - 3600);// set the time to minus to remove the cookie.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this similar problem with Chrome. Opening up the cookies panel in Web Developer Tools sometimes shows the cookie with Expires set to "Session". Upon closing the browser (not just the tab) and re-opening the browser this cookie still persists. A sure fire way to resolve this is to clear the cache. That seems to do the trick. Bottom line is that if the cookie is being shown as "session" in the browser tools, then you've set it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to unset the cookie and then set it null like this:

```
unset($_COOKIE['cookie_name']);
setcookie ( 'cookie_name', null,-1 );
```

in the first line, you unset it and then set it to null in case any further problem.